# Mongodb find and insertMany only if the matched combination does not returns to truthy

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have to insert a batch in **action** collection which looks like this:

```
[

  {

    "userId": "57ee65fef5a0c032877725db",

    "postId": "57f63ce196b01748e4712ed3",

    "type": "like"

  },

  {

    "userId": "57ee65fef5a0c032877725db",

    "postId": "57f7335223a76c0f780a44c5",

    "type": "dismiss"

  },

  {

    "userId": "57ee65fef5a0c032877725db",

    "postId": "57f7335223a76c0f780a44c5",

    "type": "dislike"

  }

]
```

Schema of actions collections looks like:

```
const ActionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    userId: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    postId: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    type: String
}, {
    timestamps: true
});
```

but before inserting I want to make sure that this specific "userId" and "postId" within this array has no matched combination in the `action collection` of db. Since a user can only perform a single action given a particular post, posted by other users.

Comment: get the postIds and userIds separately in arrays from batch and find using $and: [{ { $in : payload.userIds},  { $in : payload.postIds}  }] and do not add these documents while using insertMany. which is a bit tideous way and is buggy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haroon your question was not self explanatory but what I understand from your scenario is you need a unique set of postId **AND** userId so i think you need a compound index to be form like. Let me know if get the scenario wrong

```
anySchema.index({field1: 1, field2: 1}, {unique: true});
```

For your case it will be

```
ActionSchema.index({postId: 1, userId: 1}, {unique: true});
```

It will assure that you will always have a unique set of postId and userId

Answer (score 1):

```
'use strict';
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var accountTypeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{type:String, index: { unique: true }},
    created: {type: Date, default: Date.now()},
    deleted: {type: Number, default: 0}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('AccountType', accountTypeSchema);
```

Comment: here you can see that "name" field is unique so like wise your postIds  can also be unique and everytime you enter a duplicate value it will alert a message

Comment: I wanted something like a compound index, but thanks anyway. :)

Answer (score 0):

You mean to have set of unique postId, userId in the given JSON, no postId, userId  should repeat ?

Comment: you can define your model like this, which will prevent duplicate entries on first step and hence saves lot of work later...

'use strict';
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var accountTypeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{type:String, index: { unique: true }},
    created: {type: Date, default: Date.now()},
    deleted: {type: Number, default: 0}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('AccountType', accountTypeSchema);

Comment: A little explanation would be really helpful

Comment: Thanks, but 
 
A little explanation would be really helpful

Comment: actually syntax is getting distorted in comments..let me write in fresh answer.

Comment: you deleted it, I guess.

Comment: It's there on top.